# I want to remove controls from iframe and add a loop to the video

Tags: html, video, iframe

Here is my code below I am using for our website

```
<html>
<head><title>Answer please</title></head>
<body>
<div class="myIframe" >
    <iframe src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/gpsassests/images/images/web_video23042018_722pm.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay" scrolling = "no" width="1900px;" height="900px;" id = "vid"  seamless></iframe>
    </div>
</bod>
</html>
```

Here autoplay works perfectly but I am not able to remove controls from video and loop, I have tried every possibilities but its not happening is there any one who could help me with this??

Comment: Whats wrong with directly embedding the video using a HTML Video control?

Comment: I want video to play in mobile devices this works perfectly @Malcor

Comment: All you're doing is using an Iframe to use the browsers html video element. If you directly use a video element, or if you use an I frame, its exactly the same, except the video element will give you greater control on the element alone.

Comment: It works perfectly in desktop(video element) but when I host it doesnt play in mobile devices so i used iframe which made it worked now I want to remove controls and loop the video is there a way?

Comment: Hope you understand what I am trying to do @Malcor

Answer (score 1):

Could you not embed the video directly like so?

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Answer please</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="myIframe">
        <video src="https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/gpsassests/images/images/web_video23042018_722pm.mp4" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    </bod>

</html>
```

This way you can omit the `controls` attribute and then no controls are displayed.

Comment: No I dont want to do this way @Malcor